# KDE Plasma losing primary monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, kde, plasma

Every few reboots my taskbar jumps screens without any configuration changes.  My primary monitor will still be labeled correctly.  I then have to change the primary monitor to the screen that has stolen the taskbar.  At that point the taskbar goes back where I want.

Any suggestions?  The best suggestion I currently have is to leave KDE/plasma.

Comment: Never have experienced something like that on Kubuntu 17.04 or 16.10 prior to that. You should provide the version of Kubuntu you are using, as this sounds like a misconfiguration or Bug.

Comment: @Bruni 16.04.2 LTS  everything apt managed, 3 monitors, two of which share a resolution, the 3rd that it tends to jump to has a smaller resolution

Comment: I've got a similar problem. This thread on Gentoo discusses what seems a similar or same problem. No solution yet unfortunately: https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7942502.html